# Recover deleted SIM contacts

Tags: recovery-mode

I have an Android phone. I accidentally deleted some of my SIM contacts which were not synchronized with my gmail account (actually, I hadn't synchronized my SIM or Phone contacts ever). Is it possible to recover those deleted SIM or phone contacts using software or any other method?
Please someone help.
Thank you.

Comment: There are couple of **Contact Recovery App** on Google Play Store. You can find out them [here.](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=recover%20deleted%20contacts&hl=en) Try them as suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

You need direct access to sim memory for that to work. Any app that exchanges data (standard read and write of contacts, sms, few other id's) with sim card will pass the request to the micro controller on the sim card. And I don't think it is possible for apps to have data recovery level operations on the sim card's memory.